# How does grep deal with overlapping lines?

Tags: grep

Suppose my text file looks like this:

```
hello world1
foo bar2
hello world3
foo bar4
hello world5
foo bar
```

If I run this command  `grep  -A 4 'hello' draft.txt`, I thought it print something like this:

```
hello world1     <<<<<<< This line matches
foo bar2         <<< These lines are the printed because of -A 4
hello world3     <<<
foo bar4         <<<
hello world5     <<< 
hello world3     <<<<<<< this line matches
foo bar4         <<< These lines are printed because of -A 4
hello world5     <<<
foo bar          <<<
 ... < so on > ....
```

But what it actually does is that it prints this (which might be a feature/bug).

```
hello world1
foo bar2
hello world3
foo bar4
hello world5
foo bar
```

Is this how it is supposed to work? how do I get it to behave like what I thought it would ? (what switch/option do I use?)

Answer (score 0):

Other lines with matches count as context. You can do something to make the matches show up to make the output easier to read.

```
grep  --color -A 4 'hello' draft.txt
```

[image]

Non-contiguous groups of matches and context lines will be split up with `--` on a line by itself.